# To send data from firebase to android app

Tags: javascript, android, html, firebase

1.I have two things here which are Mobile App and Web App with Firebase database.

2.I already can insert the data into Firebase from mobile app and web app. Here is the picture.

[This is the web page for reload point with user id and point to be reload.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9R6hK.png)

[This is the data about reload point when submit button above is being clicked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/No4hp.png)

[This is the user account with user id "yunuswahab"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMYhr.png)

3.So what I want to do here is to send the reload point to the account of user through user id. What should I do? Do I have to make the user id in web app and mobile app to be the same so that the reloaded point can get by the user? Please help me.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: I'll try to use the code that given on the link @IvanRubinson